# SWIG typemap 2d array to Python list

Tags: python, c++, arrays, char, swig

This is next level of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70595876/custom-swig-accessor-functions-or-struct-member-type-cast). I need to cast 2d C char array to Python list.

Python side

```
device_info = getInfoFromCpp()
print(device_info.angles)
for angle in device_info.angles:
  print("Angel: " + angle)
```

Error

```
<Swig Object of type 'char (*)[MaxStringLength]' at 0x000000D8B2710330>
Execution error: 'SwigPyObject' object is not iterable
```

С++ header

```
struct DeviceInformation {
  static const int MaxStringLength= 200;
  static const int MaxNumberOfAngles= 5;

  char serialNumber[MaxStringLength];
  char angles[MaxNumberOfAngles][MaxStringLength];
};
```

Based on @MarkTolonen 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70602520/17782348) I try the following *typemaps* but no result.

```
// %typemap(out) char*[ANY] %{
// %typemap(out) char (*)[ANY] %{
%typemap(out) char [ANY][ANY] %{
    PyObject *pyArray = PyList_New(5);
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        PyObject *pyString = PyString_FromString(reinterpret_cast<char*>($1[i]));
        PyList_SetItem(pyArray, i, pyString);
    }
    $result = pyArray;
%}
```

Comment: What does "no result" mean?  I tested your typemap and it worked for me, although you should use `$1_dim0` instead of a hard-coded `5` for the list length for a more generic typemap.

Comment: Also, PyString is a deprecated name.  SWIG has a compatibility #define for it but the correct API is `PyUnicode_FromString`.  You also don't need to cast and can say `PyUnicode_FromString($1[i])`.  Note that PyUnicode_FromString assumes the char array is encoded in UTF-8, which may not be correct.  PyBytes_FromString() would just give the bytes with no encoding assumption.

Comment: Yes, I use `$1_dim0` too but when I tried *%typemap(out) char*[ANY]* and `%typemap(out) char (*)[ANY]` I hardcoded array size. And thanks for detailed clarification about difference between `PyUnicode_FromString`, `PyString_FromString` and `PyBytes_FromString`/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as is worked for me, but here are some corrections as mentioned in the question comments and a working example:

test.i

```cpp
%module test

// This works for any size of 2d char array assuming it contains
// UTF-8-encoded, null-terminated strings (no error checking!)
%typemap(out) char [ANY][ANY] %{
    $result = PyList_New($1_dim0);
    for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < $1_dim0; ++i) {
        PyList_SET_ITEM($result, i, PyUnicode_FromString($1[i]));
    }
%}

%inline %{
struct DeviceInformation {
  static const int MaxStringLength= 200;
  static const int MaxNumberOfAngles= 5;

  char serialNumber[MaxStringLength];
  char angles[MaxNumberOfAngles][MaxStringLength];
};

// test function
DeviceInformation getInfoFromCpp() {
    return {"serialnumber",{"angle1","angle2","angle3","angle4","angle5"}};
}
%}
```

Demo:

```
>>> import test
>>> x=test.getInfoFromCpp()
>>> x.serialNumber
'serialnumber'
>>> x.angles
['angle1', 'angle2', 'angle3', 'angle4', 'angle5']
```

Comment: Yes, my code finally works when I put *typemap* rules in most top of SWIG file right after *%module ...* directive. But without your help I am not sure I successed so quick.

Comment: @den Yes, you have to define the rules before SWIG processes the lines that create the wrapper code :)  It's a good idea to post an [mcve] like in my answers that reproduce the issue.  In the future reduce the problem to a small `test.i` and post that in the question.  It's easier to edit that with the fixes then come up with it from scratch, and it makes it clear (as in this case) that code might have been located incorrectly.